# Application is not supported in android 5.2

Tags: android, google-play, android-5.0-lollipop

Hi i developed android application but it is running in 5.2. But aftre upload to google play store if search means it is not showing in nexus tablet android 5.2`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.name"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.1.3" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />      
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

  <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

`

Comment: Are you on Android Studio?

Comment: Can you share the full manifest file

Comment: 1) play store needa several hours to updat 2)did you habe any usea-feature that makes it inkompatible to your tablet (Front cam eg) 3) I think you mean 5.0.2 which is the same SDK lvl 21

Comment: @Aspicas Iam using eclipse

Comment: @Fahim can you please check i edited

Comment: did you upload 7" tablet screenshots for your app? the console says you have to upload them to be able to find the app using tablets

Answer (score 0):

```
package="com.example.name"
```

Google play store restrict the app whose package name starts with "com.example".

Can you try uploading a new apk with different package name

Packages are typically named using the following convention:

```
[org/com].[company].[product].[component]
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the "issue".

Comment: @Fahim Example i give this package name. Actually my package name is different same what you mention

Comment: Why would you hide the package name? I thought you wanted people to download the app.